# Drawing balls from an infinite urn

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

An urn contains an infinite number of balls in three colors: red, blue, and green. The probability of drawing each color is as follows:

- Red: 0.6
- Blue: 0.3
- Green: 0.1

We continue to draw balls from the urn until a green ball is drawn. The sequence of drawn balls stops as soon as a green ball appears. For example, a sequence might look like this: RBRRBRBBRRRG.

### Objective:

We are interested in calculating the probability of drawing at least 5 blue balls (in the example above we got 4) before the first green ball is drawn (it does not matter how many red balls appear).

---

My first instinct was to calculate 1 - P(green ball).

But this is ineffective since we have the red balls.

I also cannot know the number of balls before the green one ( I suppose it could be infinite).

My only idea is that we can discard all sequences less than or equal to 5 balls.

So what method do you propose to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ignore the red balls, and pretend that you have a biased coin with two sides: blue and green.

In this biased coin, the probability of blue is $~\dfrac{.3}{.3 + .1} = \dfrac{3}{4}.~$

See also [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Then, the original question is reduced to asking for the probability that your first $~5~$ coin tosses all come up blue.  The probability must be $~\left( ~\dfrac{3}{4} ~\right)^5.$

---

As an alternate way of thinking about the problem, pretend instead that $~60\%~$ of the balls are red, that $~40\%~$ of the balls are black, and that every time that you draw a black ball, you flip the biased coin.